# Can anything be stolen from me using bank Information?

Tags: banks

I live on a Caribbean island and i am selling my pick up truck. Someone has contacted me saying they want to buy it and ship to the US.They have asked for all my bank info, IBAN, Swift Code, Acc.#, bank name and address etc... This all seems fishy to me as they can probably find the same truck in the states for cheaper and have not negotiated anything. They have not asked me to send any money or any other personal information, only all the bank info so they can send the money. If i send it am i at risk of my personal info being stolen or money being stolen from my account?

Comment: Depends on what is etc. The items you mentioned seem safe.

Comment: Perhaps you ask them directly why they want to ship?